# Need a special hidden character in iOS

Tags: ios

I'm looking for a special character that will not show in Textfield or Textview but we can get that character by coding. Is there any character like that?

Comment: Is there a reason that this character needs to be invisible to TextField and TextView. Is there a reason you can't store something in a variable? Can you explain a little more of what you are trying to achieve here?

Comment: what's the purpose of it , tell me in some more detail manner.

Comment: I'm making an custom keyboard, on keyboard there are some button that inserts a phrase or a sentence into textfield. When user taps "Delete button" I must delete the previous phrase or sentence not a character. So I need a special character like that to know where I should delete

Answer (score 3):

This character is known as "Zero-width No-break space" character

http://www.fileformat.info/info/unicode/char/200b/index.htm